# jQuery effects IE7 float issue

Tags: jquery, effects

i have a container div with a couple of divs in it that are floated left and right. When i apply an effect to the container such as fadeOut() or slideUp() in IE7 the effect only gets applied to the container and anuything in it that isnt floated. The floated elements just disappear when the effect has finished they don't do the actual effect. Anyone know of a fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it! It wasnt because of they were floated it because they positioned relative. So i just took the position relative off and used different styling to make them look how I wanted and it works fine now